# Where is the location of the pkg_extensioname.xml file after upload?

Tags: joomla-3.x

After uploading an extension package to Joomla, where is the location to 
pkg_extensioname.xml file?

Answer (score 2):

I found it myself just now, it is under:

```
administrator/manifests/packages
```

best regards
Kian William

Comment: Hi Kian, please mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the "tick" symbol underneath the voting arrows so people know this question has been answered. Thank-you.